# Trigger Azure pipeline when new branch is created in releases/*

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We want to adopt Trunk Based Development branching policy as explained [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=azure-devops)
As a part of our solution we want to trigger Azure pipeline whenever a new release branch is created from master (trunk): for example *releases/R.1*

Our current yaml for said pipeline looks like this:

```
trigger:
 branches:
  include:
  - releases/*

...
```

Unfortunately it doesn't trigger when branch is created. I suspect it will trigger when we make changes to release branch, but according to Trunk Based Development we plan to only merge cherry-picked bugfixes/hotfixes from master. Is there a way to trigger pipeline on branch creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to this doc: [Behavior of triggers when new branches are created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003781#behavior-of-triggers-when-new-branches-are-created)

> Here is the behavior when you push a new branch (that matches the branch filters) >to your repository:

> If your pipeline has path filters, it will be triggered only if the new branch has >changes to files that match that path filter.

> If your pipeline does not have path filters, it will be triggered even if there are >no changes in the new branch.

To trigger the pipeline when a new branch created, you need to remove the path filter and only set branch filter.

For example:

```
trigger:
- release/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```